# Node JS util returning: undefined

Tags: node.js

I am using the node js module util and including it in my project like so:

```
var util = require('util');
```

When I return the response like so:

```
util.inspect(response, false, null);
```

I get this output:

```
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     text: "The ReadableState Description here",
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: 
....
```

Now, when I try to get:

```
 response.IncomingMessage.ReadableState.text
```

I get the response:

> undefined

How do I get the value of text to output?

Comment: First of all , you may use `--inspect` option (ex `node --debug`) to inspect the variables. Secondly, what do you try to do? If you want to write some text to client, then use method `write` of `response`. You may store this text wherever you want before you sending it to the client.

BTW `response._readableState.text` doesn't seem to be correct way for solving task. It is private service field

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
response._readableState.text
```

Comment: Correct, the output states that `response` is an instance of `IncomingMessage` and the `_readableState` property is an instance of `ReadableState`.